# Flutter _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<TeamID>')

Tags: flutter, dart

I have calling data from and store in a List which I have defined is a list of model. But still its show error that it's List

My code

```
class TeamsController with ChangeNotifier {
  List<TeamID> teamslist = [];

  TeamsController() {
    getMyTeams();
  }

  getMyTeams() async {
    var response = await ApiService().getMyCreatedTeams();
    if (response != null) {
      final databody = json.decode(response);
      debugPrint(databody['data'].toString());
      teamslist =
          databody['data'].map((item) => TeamID.fromJson(item)).toList();

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

Its showing error on teams list that _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List')

Its working if I first store in list like this

```
final List list = databody['data'];
  teamslist = list.map((item) => TeamID.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your main list as `List<dynamic>` like this:

```js
class TeamsController with ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> teamslist = [];

  TeamsController() {
    getMyTeams();
  }

  getMyTeams() async {
    var response = await ApiService().getMyCreatedTeams();
    if (response != null) {
      final databody = json.decode(response);
      debugPrint(databody['data'].toString());
      teamslist =
          databody['data'].map((item) => TeamID.fromJson(item)).toList();

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

That would work but if you want to know the type then you can first check the type and then assign the type to it. You can the type like this:

```js
print(databody['data'].map((item) => TeamID.fromJson(item)).toList().runtimeType);
```

After that you can assign `teamslist` to that type.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown looks reasonable. Given this

```dart
  List<TeamID> teamslist = [];
  ...
      teamslist =
          databody['data'].map((item) => TeamID.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

Dart's type inference will type this assignment as you're expecting *provided that* `TeamID.fromJson()`'s return type is `TeamID`.

So please either check your definition of `TeamID.fromJson()` or post its code in your question.

(Note, there is no compelling reason to use `dynamic` in this case.)